# Why do we lose one reputation by downvoting posts?

Tags: discussion, votes, reputation

I recently found that I lose one reputation when I down-vote a post.

But why is that happening? Is that because the OP has given time to write their post? But what about posts that are bad enough to trigger down-votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The motivation behind it is to put emphasis on up-voting or not voting
> at all. This way, down votes will carry more weight and it will also
> prevent users from abusing the system by down-voting excessively.
>
> According to what the founders, Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky,
> discussed on an episode of the Stack Overflow podcast, they wanted to
> find a way to discourage users from down-voting for less legitimate
> reasons (say a pro-Java developer down-voting everything remotely
> related to .NET or the like).
>
> I have to admit, it definitely puts it into perspective to compare how
> many points you gain for other activities vs. the 1 point you lose for
> a down vote. It is effectively the smallest penalty that the Stack
> Overflow scoring system will permit.

Source: [The current top-voted answer at the Meta Stack Exchange post, "Why do you lose reputation for downvoting answers?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15866/162827)

Comment: That question was asked 14 years ago. But I experienced the reputation loss just yesterday. I have down-voted some answers before but never experienced that before.

Comment: @SnackExchange If you're referring to the meta post, its rationale still applies to this day, even if it was made 14 years ago. I believe the reputation deduction from downvoting occurs immediately when you downvote; however, the notification might not occur immediately, which is probably why you just noticed it yesterday.

Comment: You also get your points back if you downvote and it subsequently gets deleted.

Comment: It's also worth noting that even one upvote can potentially undo the reputation loss of several downvotes. So, I wouldn't let it bother you too much, whether you lose a few in downvoting or in being downvoted.